# Set the Enable Parent Paths = True of ASP Application in IIS for all available websites by Power shell Script

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to update `Enable Parent Paths = True` of ASP Application in IIS for all available websites by `Power Shell Script`.

Below is my power shell script which I tried but it works for Specific Website only.

```powershell
Set-WebConfigurationProperty `
    -PSPath MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST `
    -Location 'Default Web Site' `
    -Filter system.webServer/asp `
    -Name enableParentPaths `
    -Value true
```

Is there any way like put * in this script and it works for all website as I am not sure with that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enumerate all websites using the IIS PSDrive:

```powershell
Import-Module webadministration
Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites | select -expand Name | % { 
    Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST -Location $_ -Filter system.webServer/asp -Name enableParentPaths -Value true 
}
```

Comment: -jisaak  When I Run this script in power shell  it gives error do I need to change anything in that ? sorry I am new in Power shell so no idea about anything.

Comment: basically, I copied your snippet into the site enumeration. % is a shortcut for foreach. You can access the current sitename using $_ within the foreach loop ( %{ } ). Oh, i made a ";" in the script. I fix it - you can try it again.